# Changing get method to get XML to Post - C#

Tags: c#, post, xmlhttprequest

I am using GET to authenticate and generate XML but I want to change this to POST method instead.

Please see my code below:

```
string url = "https://www.example.com/?username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(customXertificateValidation);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

xmldoc.Load(url);
XmlNode name = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/Node/Name");
```

This above code is working fine. I just need to change this get request for authentication to post.

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible in this way. You shoud use HttpWebRequest or HttpClient for this.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen Thanks for the comment. I am now writing HttpWebRequest and I am getting an error. Can you please check this post i have just written https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453465/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-httpwebrequest-c-sharp